# Why is my touchesEnded function not initializing?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

The code will return the x1 and y1 values, but does not seem to be running through the touchesEnded function. My goal is to create  a rectangle starting at a corner where the user touches and ending where the user lifts their finger.

```
            //touch initialized
            override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
            for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self)
            let x1 = location.x
            let y1 = location.y
            print(x1,y1)

        }

            func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){
            for touch in touches{

            let location2 = touch.location(in: self)
            let x2 = location2.x
            let y2 = location2.y
            let originX = min(x1,x2)
            let originY = min(y1,y2)
            let cornerX = max(x1,x2)
            let cornerY = max(y1,y2)
            let boxWidth = cornerX - originX
            let boxHeight = cornerY - originY

            let box = SKSpriteNode()
            box.size = CGSize(width: boxWidth, height: boxHeight)
            box.color = SKColor.black
            box.position = CGPoint(x:originX, y: originY)
            addChild(box)

            print(x1,y1,x2,y2)
            }
            }
```

Comment: I think you need to override the `touchesEnded` function like you did with `touchesBegan`

Comment: Making the touchesEnded function an override function gives me an error " 'override' can only be specified on class members ".

Comment: @nowBrain Did my answer solve the problem? If so, could you please mark it as correct

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that it's missing a curly bracket to close `touchesBegan`, so `touchesEnded` is not allowed to be overridden because it's technically in your `touchesBegan` rather than in the scene itself.

Try this:

```
var x1: CGFloat = 0.0
var y1: CGFloat = 0.0

//...

//touch initialized
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        x1 = location.x
        y1 = location.y
        print(x1,y1)
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?){

    for touch in touches{
        let location2 = touch.location(in: self)
        let x2 = location2.x
        let y2 = location2.y
        let originX = min(x1,x2)
        let originY = min(y1,y2)
        let cornerX = max(x1,x2)
        let cornerY = max(y1,y2)
        let boxWidth = cornerX - originX
        let boxHeight = cornerY - originY
        let box = SKSpriteNode()
        box.size = CGSize(width: boxWidth, height: boxHeight)
        box.color = SKColor.black
        box.position = CGPoint(x:originX, y: originY)
        addChild(box)

        print(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    }
}
```

Of course, instead of saving each x and y coordinates separately, I would jut store two CGPoints

Comment: When I do this, i get error "Use of unresolved identifier 'x1'". So, can I not store information from one function to the next?